# Page won't scroll with react-scroll

Tags: reactjs, react-scroll

It looks like there is no trigger at all when I click specific item in Navbar, at one point it kinda worked, url was at least changing when I click li, but now even that doesn't work.

Beside this, I have also set the ID for each of the components.

This is App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import logo from './icons/logo.svg';

import Landing_Nav from './pages/landing/Landing_Nav';
import Landing_Hero from './pages/landing/Landing_Hero';
import Landing_Organization from './pages/landing/Landing_Organization';
import Landing_Toolkit from './pages/landing/Landing_Toolkit';
import Landing_Idea from './pages/landing/Landing_Idea';

import './styles/root.scss';

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="landing_content">
            <Landing_Nav />
            <Landing_Hero />
            <Landing_Organization />
            <Landing_Toolkit />
            <Landing_Idea />                      
        </div>
    )
}

export default App;
```

This is Landing_Nav.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import logo from '../../icons/logo.svg';

import '../../styles/root.scss';
import '../../styles/landing-navigation.scss';

import { Link } from "react-scroll";

function Landing_Nav() {
    return (
        <div className="navigation">
            <img src={logo} className="logo-img"/>
            <div className="nav-right-content">
                <ul className="nav-on-page">
                    <Link
                        activeClass=""
                        to="organization-link"
                        spy={true}
                        smooth={true}
                        offset={-70}
                        duration= {500}
                    ><li>Organization</li></Link>                              
                </ul>
                <button className="btn-primary">Create Together</button>
            </div>
        </div>                                  
    )
}

export default Landing_Nav;
```

Comment: Could you share the `Landing_Organization` component?

Comment: I'm attaching it @BitSteven, it's probably some stupid problem... it's my first time doing React - I'm Product Designer, just trying to build my own product 

https://imgur.com/gallery/Sy2ln1z

Comment: Also, when i run npm start, everything works, but nav links doesnt do anything, if i open console and click something - again, nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `Landing_Organization` component you have the `id` of that component set to `"organization-link"`. I believe you need to set the `name` attribute to `"organization-link"` for the react-scroll library to work as intended.